# How can I get the currently logged in user and prevent him from searching for himself?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The method searchForFriends retrieves users stored in firebase database based on their
usernames. However a logged in user can search for himself too.
I tried couple solutions but none worked.
I tried to get the currentuserid and transform it to string variable even though
the issue continued.

```
searchIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {

        String searchTextInput = searchText.getText().toString();
        searchForFriends(searchTextInput);
        }
    });

private void searchForFriends(String searchTextInput)
{
    Toast.makeText(FindFriendsActivity.this, "Searching...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Query searchForPeople = usersRef.orderByChild("username")
            .startAt(searchTextInput).endAt(searchTextInput+"\uf8ff");
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<FindFriends> options
            = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<FindFriends>()
            .setQuery(searchForPeople,FindFriends.class).build();
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<FindFriends,FindFriendsViewHolder> adapter
            = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<FindFriends, FindFriendsViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FindFriendsViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull FindFriends model)
        {
            holder.userFullName.setText(model.getFullname());
            holder.userStatus.setText(model.getStatus());
            Picasso.get().load(model.getProfileimage()).into(holder.userProfileImage);


        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public FindFriendsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
        {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.show_searched_users,parent,false);
            FindFriendsViewHolder viewHolder = new FindFriendsViewHolder(view);
            return viewHolder;
        }
    };

    searchResults.setAdapter(adapter);
     adapter.startListening();

}

public static class FindFriendsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    TextView userFullName, userStatus;
    CircleImageView userProfileImage;
    public FindFriendsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);
        userFullName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.show_searched_users_full_name);
        userStatus = itemView.findViewById(R.id.show_searched_users_status);
        userProfileImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.searched_user_profile_image);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Which specific line in this code doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen If I've read it correctly, if the current user has a username of "userB", and they search "user", the current user's username is in the list in addition to other matches. They are looking for a query that can use with startAt/endAt but exclude their own username - so pretty much something like "starts with `searchTextInput` but not equal to `currentUsername`"

Comment: Ah... yeah... no. :) You'll have to skip that node in the application code.